# gem 1.8.10 error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I just setup an EC2 instance on ubuntu and installed ruby 1.9.2. I also updated the rubygems by executing gem update --system. Once the installation was done, I typed gem -v and I got the following error

```
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/tilt-1.3.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/specifications/rack-cache-1.0.3.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-08-27 00:00:00.000000000Z"
1.8.10
```

Comment: Try going to the two files specified, and remove everything in the date string after the period, and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. You must delete everything except the actual date (not time).

As such, "2011-08-25 00:00:00.000000000Z" should become "2011-08-25". That will fix the annoying messages, as well as allow 'gem' to see that those are installed.

By the way, a newer rack-cache (1.1 vs 1.0.3) is available that does not have this problem.  However, since gem doesn't think 'rack-cache' is installed, you'll have to manually delete all of the files.  You can do that using:

sudo find /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/ -name '*rack-cache-1.0.3*' -exec rm -fR {} \;